# Is it possible to find value of dynamic groups using Java regexp?

Tags: java, regex

If I have the text like

```
"Record with text1 Record with text2 Record with text3"
```

and I know: number of Records will be from 2 to 10,
is it possible to use regexp?:

```
Pattern.compile("(Record.*){2,10}");
```

And how can I get the values of records?

```
"Record with text1"
"Record with text2"
"Record with text3"
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible to use a regular expression to capture your matches. You can use a **negative lookahead** assertion here to find where the previous match stops and continue matching.

```
String s  = "Record with text1 Record with text2 Record with text3";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?i)\\brecord(?:(?!record).)+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Outputs

```
Record with text1 
Record with text2 
Record with text3
```

Regular expression:

```
(?i)           set flags for this block (case-insensitive)
 \b            the boundary between a word char (\w) and not a word char
  record       'record'
 (?:           group, but do not capture (1 or more times)
  (?!          look ahead to see if there is not:
    record     'record'
  )            end of look-ahead
  .            any character except \n
 )+            end of grouping
```

I would consider `split`ing the records in this case to consume your matches.

```
String s = "Record with text1 Record with text2 Record with text3";
String[] parts = s.split("(?<!\\A)(?=(?i:record\\b))");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

Outputs

```
[Record with text1 , Record with text2 , Record with text3]
```

Regular expression:

```
(?<!          look behind to see if there is not:
\A            the beginning of the string
)             end of look-behind
(?=           look ahead to see if there is:
 (?i:         group, but do not capture (case-insensitive)
  record      'record'
  \b          the boundary between a word char (\w) and not a word char
 )            end of grouping
)             end of look-ahead
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you mean by "use" the regex, but if you mean to *check* that the input contains 2-10 "records", then this will work:

```
if (input.matches("(Record.*?){2,10}"))
```

To split out the records into an array of separate Strings:

```
String[] records = input.split("(?=Record)");
```

Since you want to preserve the text "Record" in your results, the regex can't *consume* "Record", so a look ahead has been used.

Answer (score 0):

If your records are in separate lines then you can just use

```
Pattern.compile("^Record.*");
```

Next with `Matcher` you can create something like

```
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

to print all lines that starts with word `Record`.

---

If by *value of record* you mean part after `Record` then you can use this pattern

```
Pattern.compile("^Record\\s+(.*)");
```

and call `group(1)` (this will return part matched inside *first* parenthesis) on your `matcher`.

---

Another approach would be using look-ahead to determine place where match should stop like

```
Pattern.compile("\\bRecord(.(?!Record))*+");
```

but that may overcomplicate things. It would be simpler if there was some special character between your records so we could use it at the end of our regex (now this special separator is another word `Record`).

Comment: But if all records in one line?

Comment: @user2602807 Are there separated somehow? Is there at least space between them?